# how to make decode unction that can rearrange and sorting input based on integer input?

Tags: python

I wanna make a function named decode. It can rearrange the sort's list of input_string1 based on input_srting2.

Example:

```
input_string1 = "a,b,c"
input_string2 = "2,0,1"

ouput = : "c,a,b"
```

\

```
def decode(input_string1, input_string2):

try:
    input_string_1 = int(input_string_2)
except ValueError:
    value = input_string_2.lower()
return value
```

Answer (score 0):

If the indices in the second string are separated by `sep`, then the following implementation works:

```py
def decode(s1: str, s2: str, sep=','):
    return sep.join(s1.split(sep)[int(i)] for i in s2.split(sep))
```

Comment: but how to rearrange and sort the input_string1 based on the number in input_string2

Comment: it's error : return ''.join(input_string_1[int(c)] for c in input_string_2)
IndexError: string index out of range